# Cannot set http POST headers in desired format (using libcurl)

Tags: c, rest, http, curl, libcurl

I am working on a REST client which uses libcurl to send HTTP POST Messages.

After receiving HTTP POST packet, My REST server needs to take some action, but it is unable to do that because some headers differ from the expected format.

Required HTTP Packet Format:

```
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
> Accept: text/html
> Content-Type: text/plain 

Line-based text data: text/plain
>test string
```

Current HTTP Packet Format:

```
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Line-based text data: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>test string
```

I have tried the following: (Reference: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/httpcustomheader.html)

```
curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) 
{
    struct curl_slist *chunk = NULL;


    /* Add a custom header */ 
    chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Accept: text/html");
    chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Content-Type: text/plain");

    /* set our custom set of headers */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, chunk);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

But this code change has NO EFFECT on the outgoing HTTP POST packet.

Can anyone please suggest me what libcurl options can help me achieve the desired format?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you've included a call like `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);` after the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`, could that be it?

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem. It was a legacy code and the options I was setting were being overwritten later.